# How to create a notification balloon on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to create a simple command line tool to post quick notifications like this.

[image]

I want the tool to be as simple and small as possible. So I choose to code in CPP, and use Win32 API directly.

I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#display_notification) guide very useful. But it seems this `Shell_NotifyIcon` API requires a valid `hWnd` handler, which means I will have to create a hidden/invisible window in my command line tool, which I'd rather not.

Any better idea on how to create a notification on Windows?

Comment: *"I want the tool to be as simple and small as possible. So I choose to code in CPP"* - .NET assemblies are in all likeliness smaller. If file size matters, then you may not have picked the right platform.

Comment: .Net app would be smaller but has to depends on .Net run time. I'd want my tool to not depends on .Net as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell notification API requires that you supply a window handle. So create a message only window and use that as the owner of the notification icon and balloons.

That you would prefer not to create a window in your console app is understandable but the API is what it is. You don't get to re-write system APIs for your convenience. You just have to go along with them.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that easily with no need to use [ATL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/active-template-library-atl-concepts?view=msvc-170) or [MFC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-desktop-applications?view=msvc-170), just pure [Win32 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/), which can be a Console application as well.

First you need the icon image. Store it in your **resource.h** file

```
#define IDI_BATTERY_IMAGE             101
```

add an **.rc** file to your project with the following line

```
IDI_BATTERY_IMAGE             ICON                    "Battery.ico"
```

**Bonus tip**: you can find free images to download, like [this](https://icon-icons.com/icon/battery-charging/934) one. Just make sure to call it "Battery.ico" and place it in the path of your other source files.

Best if you create a separate pair of **.cpp** and **.h** files for the notification balloon functionality.
In your **.cpp** file place the following code:

```
// tray icon data
NOTIFYICONDATA m_NID;

BOOL CreateTrayIcon()
{
    memset(&m_NID, 0, sizeof(m_NID));
    m_NID.cbSize = sizeof(m_NID);

    m_NID.uID = IDI_BATTERY_IMAGE;

    // set handle to the window that receives tray icon notifications
    m_NID.hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();

    // fields that are being set when adding tray icon 
    m_NID.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON;

    // set image
    m_NID.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_BATTERY_IMAGE));

    if (!m_NID.hIcon)
        return FALSE;

    m_NID.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4;

    if (!Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &m_NID))
        return FALSE;

    return Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_SETVERSION, &m_NID);
}

BOOL ShowTrayIconBalloon(LPCTSTR pszTitle, LPCTSTR pszText, UINT unTimeout, DWORD dwInfoFlags)
{
    m_NID.uFlags |= NIF_INFO;
    m_NID.uTimeout = unTimeout;
    m_NID.dwInfoFlags = dwInfoFlags;

    if (StringCchCopy(m_NID.szInfoTitle, sizeof(m_NID.szInfoTitle), pszTitle) != S_OK)
        return FALSE;

    if (StringCchCopy(m_NID.szInfo, sizeof(m_NID.szInfo), pszText) != S_OK)
        return FALSE;

    return Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, &m_NID);
}
```

In your header file place the following:

```
BOOL CreateTrayIcon();
BOOL ShowTrayIconBalloon(LPCTSTR pszTitle, LPCTSTR pszText, UINT unTimeout, DWORD dwInfoFlags);
```

In your main function add the following code:

```
CreateTrayIcon();
ShowTrayIconBalloon(L"27 percent remaining", L"Your battary has such and such percentage...", 1000, NULL);
```

The following code was tested with a simple Console app.

Comment: Should it work on Win10 ?

Comment: Yes. Of course.

Comment: Thanks!  It does indeed work on Win10 despite of Microsoft's effort to [make the notification area always invisible](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/unhiding-notification-area-icons-taskbarsystray-no/6973882e-e74b-4fb1-a637-d3709f4e7dc1).  I'm afraid it might mean they want to disable its old-style notifications in favor of new "toast balloons"

Comment: You are welcome! Yes. I use it from Windows 10. It should also work on Windows 11.

Comment: BTW, `GetConsoleWindow` seems to be a more accurate replacement for `GetForegroundWindow` in your code: `GetForegroundWindow` might return HWND of another process window if your application window is currently not foreground.

Comment: That is correct. But even better, find the current process running and then its window