# How can I post Windows notifications from an MFC Application?

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc

How can I post Windows notifications like the one below from an MFC Application?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874190/how-to-create-a-notification-balloon-on-windows

Comment: Or this one: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/74/Adding-Icons-to-the-System-Tray

Comment: That is done by Toast notification, it's not that easy in c++ as far as I know. You can just create a popup window with animation, put it in the corner.

Comment: [Quickstart: Sending a toast notification from the desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/quickstart-sending-desktop-toast) and [How to enable desktop toast notifications through an AppUserModelID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/enable-desktop-toast-with-appusermodelid). If you don't want to create a short-cut see [Where to Assign an AppUserModelID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/appids#where-to-assign-an-appusermodelid) instead.